# How to change font size in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I decided to add radar chart to the site, however I ran into a problem. The text around the radar is very small, and despite the addition of an option to increase it, the text remains the same

```
var marksCanvas = document.getElementById("marksChart");

        var marksData = {
            labels: ["HTML 5", "CSS 3", "FLUTTER", "PYTHON", "JS", "DART", "React", "ThreeJS"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "MY SKILLS",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(30,30,32,0.4)",
                data: [90, 80, 60, 75, 60, 35, 55, 37]
              },
            ],
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            font: {
                                size: 400
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Option font: size doesn't work despite the fact that it is in the code

Comment: Is this a radialLinear scale point label? If so, per the docs font size does not apply to it. 'Default font size (in px) for text. Does not apply to radialLinear scale point labels.' https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with Chart JS V3:

```js
var marksCanvas = document.getElementById("marksChart");

var marksData = {
  labels: ["English", "Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "History"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Student A",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(200,0,0,0.2)",
    data: [65, 75, 70, 80, 60, 80]
  }, {
    label: "Student B",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,200,0.2)",
    data: [54, 65, 60, 70, 70, 75]
  }]
};

var radarChart = new Chart(marksCanvas, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: marksData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        pointLabels: {
          font: {
            size: 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="marksChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```